# Atribuir mais de um valor a um checkbox

Tags: php, html

Estou com uma duvida relativamente trivial, mas não achei em nenhum lugar a solução.

Quando declaro a seguinte tag

```
 echo '         
                                <tr>
                                <td align="center">'.$skill.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$nome.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$dataconvertida.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$desc.'</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.$codigo.' name="check[]"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                ';
```

estou atribuindo o valor codigo ao checkbox, é possivel eu atribuir mais de um valor ao checkbox? por exemplo codigo , nome.

Comment: Essa `tag` está a ser escrita por meio de um `echo` ? Se sim coloque o `echo` também para ficar mais claro como o abriu e como está a fechar

Comment: Fiz a adição de toda a tag Echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um array multidimensional no checkbox.

No nome ex:

```
echo '         
<tr>
    <td align="center">'.$skill.'</td>
    <td>'.$nome.'</td>
    <td>'.$dataconvertida.'</td>
    <td>'.$desc.'</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.$codigo.' name="check['.$codigo.']['.$nome.'][]"/>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

Ou no valor, com json_encode

```
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.json_encode([$codigo => $nome]).' name="check['.$codigo.']['.$nome.'][]"/>
```

Comment: Eu consigo recuperar esses dados por meio de um POST? por exemplo se eu fizer

$_POST['check[0] -> codigo 
$_POST['check[1] -> nome

Comment: Consegue por $_POST['check'][0]

Comment: vou testar aqui

Comment: Funcionou man, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma concatenação para obter o resultado esperado.

Acho que assim funcionará

```
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.$codigo.$nome.' name="check[]"
```

Comment: usando dessa forma ele ainda reconhece só o codigo, não leu o segundo campo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o atributo data do html5 para guardar data "extra" na sua checkbox, ou então inserir os valores delimitados por algum simbolo.

Exemplos:

```js
function imprimeValores(){
var el = document.getElementById("teste");

console.log(`O valor da checkbox é ${el.value} A data guardada na checkbox é ${el.getAttribute("data-nome")}`);

}


function imprimeValores2(){
var el = document.getElementById("teste2");
el = el.value.split("-");
console.log(`O valor da checkbox é ${el[0]} A data guardada na checkbox é ${el[1]}`);

}
```

```html
<label for="teste">Clique para ver os valores com data-nome</label><input id="teste" type="checkbox" value="codigo1" data-nome="teste" onclick="imprimeValores()"/>
</br>
<label for="teste2">Clique para ver os valores separados por virgula</label><input id="teste2" type="checkbox" value="codigo2-nome2"  onclick="imprimeValores2()"/>
```

Agora vai depender como você irá usar estes dados.

[Referência a data-atributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Como ainda não posso comentar abaixo do comentário do [gabrielfalieri](http://gabrielfalieri), eu creio que a linha de código dele está com um problema na concatenação, no qual resulta ainda em pegar somente o valor do primeiro campo.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.$codigo.$nome.' name="check[]">'.$codigo.$nome;
```

Como observação do código acima, não sei se você fechou com o ">" no final, caso sim, ignore essa observação.

Deixei conforme o seu código para não ter que trocar muita coisa, creio que só substituir o input dentro do seu código por este de cima, funcione sem problemas.

```
value='.$codigo.$nome.'
```

Deixei no final do código após o ">" para encerrar o input os valores do campo `$codigo` e `$nome` para mostrar que a concatenação está funcionando, deixei a mesma concatenação para aparecer ao lado do checkbox na página html o valor de `$nome` e `$codigo`:

`>'.$codigo.$nome;`

Creio que agora deva funcionar a concatenação dos valores certinho.